# Twitter SDK for cocoa (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mgtwitterengine

I'm looking for a simple Twitter SDK for cocoa (OSX app). I've heard about [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) but it's been like 2 years since last commit so I'm wondering if you guys have another one to recommend :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MGTwitterEngine` has not been updated because it is not needed anymore. OS X provides two frameworks that provide building blocks to create authenticated requests to social services.

- [Accounts.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024) gives you access to accounts configured by the user in Mountain Lion. See the `ACAccountStore` and `ACAccount` classes.
- [Social.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) provides you with a `SLRequest` class to make authenticated requests on behalf of an `ACAccount`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought that those were frameworks for iOS only ^_^ My bad